# How to fix semi-random black screen after login?

Tags: login, screen

Apparently I have a problematic GTX580 video card.

I followed instructions somewhere and installed Ubuntu 12.04 using "nomodeset".
Then I logged into recovery mode, got the updates, also initiated "nvidia-current" package.

The problem is I now get black screen instead of desktop (after normally logging in) like 30% of the time. It is quite odd especially when I don't know what key combination to press in that situation - I just mash my buttons and computer restarts soon (maybe CTRL+ALT+DEL causes it?). 
At other times everything is fine, actually I am smoothly typing this message using that very same Ubuntu.

How should I deal with this problem? How to act when I see a black screen? Maybe there are error logs somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you add the drivers (Nvidia-current) in the first place?

Comment: What should I add instead? Without it system is now unusable because of screen artifacts and freezing.